# With SFML 1.6, what is the best way to count button presses?

Tags: loops, count, keypress, sfml

For Example:

```
int count;

//Code to count key presses here

sf::String String("You have pressed a key this many times: " + count );
```

I already know how to convert the int to a string and insert it.

Answer (score 1):

Use events:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    // Create the main window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");
    int count = 0;
    while (window.IsOpened())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.GetEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.Close();
            if (event.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.Key.Code == sf::Key::A)
                ++count;
        }
        window.Clear();
        // Do whatever you want with count.
        window.Display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```